# How to create and populate dummy rows in tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I am working with some monthly data and I would like to convert it to daily data by creating and populating some dummy rows, as the question suggests.

For example, say I have the following data:

```
date       index
2013-04-30  232
2013-05-31  232
2013-06-30  233
```

Is there an "easy" way, preferably through `tidyverse`, that I could convert the above data into daily data, assuming I keep the index constant throughout the month? For example, I would like to create another 29 rows for April, ranging from `2013-04-01` to `2013-04-29` with the index of the last day of the month which would be `232` for April. The same should be applied to the rest of months (I have more data than just those three months).

Any intuitive suggestions will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `complete` and `fill` from `tidyr` you could do:

```r
dat <- structure(list(
  date = structure(c(15825, 15856, 15886), class = "Date"),
  index = c(232L, 232L, 233L)
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -3L
))

library(tidyr)

dat |> 
  complete(date = seq(as.Date("2013-04-01"), as.Date("2013-06-30"), "day")) |> 
  fill(index, .direction = "up")
#> # A tibble: 91 × 2
#>    date       index
#>    <date>     <int>
#>  1 2013-04-01   232
#>  2 2013-04-02   232
#>  3 2013-04-03   232
#>  4 2013-04-04   232
#>  5 2013-04-05   232
#>  6 2013-04-06   232
#>  7 2013-04-07   232
#>  8 2013-04-08   232
#>  9 2013-04-09   232
#> 10 2013-04-10   232
#> # … with 81 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! However, may I know what `|>` is and when it is used? I am only familiar with `%>%`

Comment: `|>` is the native pipe which I now part of R itself, i.e. you don't need to load a package. But you can safely replace it by `%>%` (while the reverse does not work in all cases).

Comment: Since R 4.2 introduced `_` as a placeholder for the native pipe similar to `.` in magrittr, it is also no longer always  replaceable in that direction